# Is there a type-safe way to pass an empty list as an argument in java?

Tags: java, list, generics

The following code gives a compile error:

```
public void method(List<String> aList) {}

public void passEmptyList() {
    method(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Is there a way to pass an empty list to `method` without

- Using an intermediate variable
- Casting
- Creating another list object such as `new ArrayList<String>()`

?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Replace

```
method(Collections.emptyList());
```

with

```
method(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

The `<String>` after the `.` is an explicit binding for `emptyList`'s type parameter, so it will return a `List<String>` instead of a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the type param like so:

```
public void passEmptyList() {
    method(Collections.<String>emptyList());
}
```